# Pass on variable sql queries in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

This query works when entered into phpMyAdmin however I cannot get it to work in PHP:

> SET @cnt = 0; UPDATE groupsnumber SET ordering = @cnt := (@cnt+1) ORDER BY name

This is the code I have tried:

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

 $resSrt =$mysqli->query("SET @cnt = 0; 
                         UPDATE groupsnumber 
                         SET ordering = @cnt := (@cnt+1) ORDER BY name"); 

 if (!$resSrt) 
 {
     echo "Error executing query: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error; 
 }
```

Here is the error message:

> Error executing query: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'UPDATE groupsnumber SET ordering = @cnt :=
>   (@cnt+1) ORDER BY name' at line 1

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple reason :

In

```
SET @cnt = 0; UPDATE groupsnumber SET ordering = @cnt:= (@cnt+1) ORDER BY name"
```

You are trying to execute 2 queries through single `$mysqli->query` function.

- `SET` as first query
- `Update` as second query

`mysqli_` doesn't allow multiple queries to be run through its single $mysqli->query, this is the reason why its secure and preferred as an option to prevent sql_injections.

Divide them is 2 separate queries and your are good to go!! :)

Comment: I thought the second query would not know the first set @cnt value if I divide it in 2 separate queries. But it seems to work. Thanks!!!